# .Net Com object can't be created from vbs

Tags: .net, com, com-interop, legacy

I have created com object for legacy apps (.net framework 3.5)

```
[ComVisible(true), Guid("...")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface MyComInterface
{
...
}


[ComVisible(true), Guid("...")]
[ProgId("...")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public MyComObject: MyComInterface
{
 ... 
}
```

it installs fine and everything ok in registry (progid, clsid)
I can create instance and use it from .net applications:

```
var t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("myProgID");
var o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

But vbs file

```
set o = CreateObject("myProgID")
```

argues with error: 0x80070002 (file not found)

What can be wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try either:

1. Installing the assembly containing the .Net COM object to the GAC.
2. Or using the `/codebase` option of [regasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to specify an absolute path to the assembly containing the .Net COM object.

You might also try copying the assembly to some location on the path or alongside the VBScript file, but I don't know if this will work or not.

You should also look into using Fusion logging to log assembly bind failures - this might give you some clues.

Comment: Thank you, @Kragen. The reason was assembly my com object referrenced was missed during installation. This assembly has to be in the same folder as my com object library. My .net client application was able to create my com object instance just because it referenced that assembly.